# $wpdb->get_results() not working

Tags: php, wordpress

I'm creating my own favorite posts solution, because the plugin did not work.
So I created a new table in my WP database called wp_favorites with 2 cols user ID and post ID.
I've already done the insertion and it works. I'm having a problem getting the data from the table. Here's the code:

```
function is_favorite($pid, $uid) 
{
    global $wpdb;

    $q = $wpdb->prepare("SELECT * FROM wp_favorites WHERE uid=$uid AND pid=$pid;");
    echo $q;
    $res = $wpdb->get_results($q);
    var_dump($res);
    return(count($res)>0);
}
```

When I copy the output ($q) and insert it in PHPmyAdmin, it works perfectly.
However, the output of $res is always an empty array (array(0) { } )
I've tried without prepare, and a couple of other variations, but I can't get it to work.

Same thing happens when I try to display the fav posts.

```
    <?php
/*
Template Name: Favorites
*/
?>

<?php 

get_header();
get_sidebar();

global $wpdb;
$q = "
    SELECT * FROM wp_favorites
    LEFT JOIN wp_posts ON wp_favorites.pID = wp_posts.ID
    WHERE wp_favorites.uID = 1      
";

 $pageposts = $wpdb->get_results($q, OBJECT);

 var_dump($pageposts);

?>

    <div id='content_and_floater'>

        <?php get_template_part('social_floater'); ?>
        <div id='content'>
            <?php get_template_part('loop'); ?>
        </div>

    </div>

<?php
get_footer();
?>
```

The result is, again, an empty array.
Any ideas ?

Answer (score 1):

The problem is sql statement $q = $wpdb->prepare("SELECT * FROM wp_favorites WHERE uid=$uid AND pid=$pid;");

When you use prepare you need to use placeholders . I have corrected code here:

```
$uid='3';// you can assign correct digits
$pid='5';$q = $wpdb->prepare("SELECT * FROM wp_favorites WHERE uid=%d AND pid=%d", $uid, $pid);
```

Answer (score 1):

I was sitting with this problem too. I run my query through Mysql Workbench and returns a result. then run through the program and returns no result.

My problem was that I had changed a value in workbench and had not commit my change.

Answer (score 0):

**Sample Database Table**

```
| uid | pid |
|-----|-----|
| 1   | 10  |
| 1   | 5   |
```

**PHP Function & Test Case**

```
function is_favorite($pid, $uid)
{
  global $wpdb;
  $results = $wpdb->get_results( $wpdb->prepare("SELECT * FROM wp_favorites WHERE uid=$uid AND pid=$pid"), ARRAY_A );
  print_r($results);
  return (count($results) > 0);
}

echo 'Test 1';
$test1 = $this->is_favorite(10, 1);
var_dump($test1);

echo 'Test 2';
$test2 = $this->is_favorite(100, 1);
var_dump($test1);
```

**Test Results/Printout**

```
Test 1
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [uid] => 1
            [pid] => 10
        )

)
bool(true)

Test 2
Array
(
)
bool(true)
```

Tested on WordPress 3.4.1

Comment: I copy-pasted your code and it still doesn't work. I know it should, because there is no logical explanation for it not to work, but it doesn't.

Comment: I have the same issue with the_author(). It should work, and it works when it's called second time, but it doesn't work in the main loop. Strange...

Comment: In my example code, note that I use "$this->"... I built and tested the code in a class(OOP).

From your example it appears you are not using a class so when you copy-pasted my code make sure to remove "$this->".

If the code isn't large, could attempt to convert it into a class OOP style and see if that makes any difference..

Answer (score -4):

I *believe* it should be `get_result()` not `get_results()`.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post - you can always comment on your own posts, and once you have sufficient [reputation](http://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](http://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment).

Comment: @AustinMullins I can't comment on posts due to insufficient "reputation".

Comment: If you post one good answer or question, you will have the necessary 10 points.

Comment: @AustinMullins It requires 50 points, and getting points is impossible, in my experience. People are very condescending here. I had my previous account banned for a few "stupid" questions. It had over 20 points, iirc. I'll just continue to try help where I can and if I get banned, so be it. Until the rules change or a better site emerges, that's just how it will be for me and probably many others.